# Angular 6 routing to lazy loaded nested modules

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I recently started working with Angular 6 and while basic scenarios work pretty well, I'm having a hard time making more complex routing scenarios work.

I have so far divided my application up into two major modules (more to come), Authentication and Core.

In the Core module, I have a Core Component which contains Navigation, Header and Footer Components and then a  tag.

From the core navigation the user should be able to access major parts of the application such as:

1. UsersModule - UserListComponent, AddUserComponent, EditUserComponent etc
2. ProductsModule - ProductListComponent, AddProductComponent, EditProductComponent etc.

As these different modules will be used by different users I was hoping to use lazy loading to load them into the CoreComponent - router-outlet tag. Ultimately it will look like this:

[image]

The problem is I'm not sure how to set up my routing as when I try to load any of the components in either UserModule or ProductModule they just replace the contents of the screen instead of being loaded into the CoreComponent's  tag.

Here is the code:

**app.module.ts**

[image]

**core.module.ts**

[image]

**user.module.ts**

[image]

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: in core.module.ts the path of the childroute should be /users or something i think

Comment: Are searching something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsagmd. Inside click on `family profile`

Comment: @mr.void when I change the path to /users it will replace the entire view with only the UsersListComponent instead of loading the component inside the CoreComponent's router-oulet tag.

Comment: @ShashikantDevani that is exactly what I'm looking for. Could you please explain how it works? I see that your FamilyModule is routing to "profile" and lazy loads the MemberModule as a child path, but your MemberModule is routing to "profile" as well, this time just to the MemberProfileComponent? Would that not result in a "profile/profile" route?